# Autoconf has trouble recognizing m4

Tags: autoconf

I am on macOS Sierra and I want to install the GNU autotools. So I previously installed m4 and made it available in my PATH.`which m4`     return `/Users/adrien/dev/m4/bin/m4` (I install all the GNU tools in the folder $HOME/dev) and when I ran the configuration script of autoconf it find m4 in the right directory but it says me :

```
checking for GNU M4 that supports accurate traces...   /Users/adrien/dev/m4
checking whether /Users/adrien/dev/m4 accepts --gnu... no
configure: WARNING: the version of M4 that was found does not support -g
configure: WARNING: using it with POSIXLY_CORRECT set may cause problems
```

but `m4 --version return m4 (GNU M4) 1.4.17` and `man m4` return

```
-g, --gnu
    override -G to re-enable GNU extensions
```

Everything looks good m4 supports -g and --gnu, so I dont understand why the configuration script doesn't recognized it well.

The reason I worried about it is because I previously tried to install autoconf and `make installcheck` returned an error and, once autoconf is installed, automake doesn't recognized autoconf even if it is available in my path

Comment: `/Users/adrien/dev/m4` (what `configure` finds) may not be `/Users/adrien/dev/m4/bin/m4` (what you are expecting `configure` to find).